# How do you make a tight box using \begin{framed} and how do you skiplines in it?

Tags: line-breaking, boxes, framed

I cant fit a tight box using this code:

```
\begin{framed}
\begin{flushleft}
\# Description of the data \\ 
summary(training) \end{flushleft}
\end{framed}
```

and I dont manage to skip lines.

Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by skip lines?

Comment: how do you leave a blank line between 2 lines of text so in our case between 'Description of the data' and 'summary(training)'?

Comment: OK. Fitting means you want the frame to tightly enclose the contents? Are you tied to `framed` or open to other suggestions like `tcolorbox`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be you are trying to type some kind of code and in that case you should be using `listings` or `tcblisting` (from `tcolorbox`)

This is an option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\begin{document}
\noindent
{%%<-- begin a group to make \fboxsep=0pt local
\fboxsep=0pt
\fbox{%
\begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}
\# Description of the data \\

summary(training)
\end{varwidth}
}
}%%<-- end  group
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|@{}l@{}|}\hline
\# Description of the data\\
                         \\
summary(training)\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

And `tcolorbox`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox,varwidth}
\newtcbox{\tightbox}{colback=white,arc=0pt,boxsep=0pt,left=0pt,right=0pt,top=0pt,bottom=0pt,
                    boxrule=0.5pt,varwidth upper}

% or simpler with same effect
% \newtcbox{\tightbox}{colback=white,size=tight,varwidth upper}  %% thanks to Ignasi.

\begin{document}
  \tightbox{
\# Description of the data\\

summary(training)
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is a sample of `tcblistings` for completeness

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings,skins}
\tcbset{enhanced,width=4.4cm,colframe=black, listing only, colback=white,arc=0pt,boxsep=0pt,left=0pt,right=0pt,top=0pt,bottom=0pt,
                    boxrule=0.5pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcblisting}{}
\# Description of the data

summary(training)
\end{tcblisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You have to adjust the width yourself.

Comment: Or just: `\newtcbox{\tightbox}{colback=white,size=tight,varwidth upper}`

Comment: @Ignasi True. I wanted to show all the parameters explicitly so that OP can change them if he/she wants to. I will add a note though. Thanks :-)